# AIME 1998 #9 Alternative solution

Tags: calculus, probability, contest-math

> Two mathematicians take a morning coffee break each day. They arrive at the cafeteria independently, at random times between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., and stay for exactly $m$ minutes. The probability that either one arrives while the other is in the cafeteria is $40 \%,$ and $m = a - b\sqrt {c},$ where $a, b,$ and $c$ are positive integers, and $c$ is not divisible by the square of any prime. Find $a + b + c.$

I'm going to refer to from 9am to 10am as the interval $(0,60)$. I have for the chance that either one arrives while the other is there from $(m,60-m)$ is the chance one arrives in that interval multiplied by the chance the other arrives while the first one is there.

[image]

So I have $(\frac{60-m-m}{60})(\frac{2m}{60-2m})=\frac{2m}{60}$

**Question**: is there a way of using calculus to find the probability either one arrives while the other is there if the first mathematician comes in from $(0,m)$? And I assume the probability from $(60-m,60)$ is the same.

**My attempt**: Let $m=5$ then suppose the 1st mathematician comes from $(3,3.1)$, also *assume* we use the lower number then the range the 2nd mathematician can come in from is $(0,8)$. So the probability in that case would be $(\frac{\frac{1}{10}}{60})(\frac{8}{60})$. If that's correct then let the small range the 1st mathematician comes in be $dx$. **So I have**:  $\int_{0}^{m} (\frac{x+m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})$. Is what I'm doing correct?

Comment: The way I think about it is a 2D plot with the axes being when each mathematician arrives.

Comment: Yeah I know that's the solution the test writers provide. I was wondering if there was an alternative solution using calculus similar to what I did. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You can collapse the 2D plot into 1D but the result is essentially the same. Finding the area can be computed with basic calculus.

Comment: What is AIME abbreviation for?

Comment: @Emptymind American Invitational Math Examination

Comment: 1D case is also given at https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1998_AIME_Problems/Problem_9 but I don't find it as clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculus way of doing this question is

> $$2\int_{0}^{m} (\frac{x+m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})+\int_{m}^{60-m}(\frac{2m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})=\frac{4}{10}$$

Let be m equal to a specific number for example 5, then suppose this is on the interval $(0,60)$, then if the 1st person comes in between $(2,2.1)$ then, by assumption, use the lower number, in this case 2, to determine the range the 2nd person can come, which is (0,2+5). The probability the 1st person arrives in between (2,2.1) is $\frac{1}{600}$, the probability the 2nd person arrives in between $(0,2+5)$ is $\frac{7}{60}$, so you have $\frac{7}{36000}$. Now, we make the range the 1st person comes to be small in the case above $(2,2+dx)$. And then let the arrival time of the 1st person be $x$ and the range be $dx$ and use $m$ instead of 5. The probability (and I'm considering the interval $(0,m)$) that either one arrives while the other is there is $(\frac{x+m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})$. Now sum each of these probabilities from 0 to $m$. You have: $$\int_{0}^{m} (\frac{x+m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})$$.

Now for a fixed time inside the interval $(m,60-m)$ the probability the 1st person arrives in the range $(x,x+dx)$ is $\frac{dx}{60}$. The probability the 2nd person arrives while the other is there is $\frac{2m}{60}$. Sum each of these from $m$ to $60-m$. You have:
$$\int_{m}^{60-m}(\frac{2m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})$$

The interval $(60-m,60)$ is symmetric to $(0,m)$ so we multiply the first integral by 2 to give:

$$2\int_{0}^{m} (\frac{x+m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})+\int_{m}^{60-m}(\frac{2m}{60})(\frac{dx}{60})=\frac{4}{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=\{(x,y)\in[0,60]^2: |x-y|\leqslant m\}$. The probability that either mathematician arrives while the other is in the cafeteria is given by the area of $S$ divided by the area of $[0,60]^2$, so the probability of the complement event satisfies
$$
\frac{(60-m)^2}{60^2} = 1-\frac25.
$$
Solving the above yields $m=60-12\sqrt{15}$ (the other root is not within $[0,60]$ and thus is not a valid solution), so $m=a-b\sqrt c$ with $a,b$ and $c$ positive integers and $c=3\cdot5$ not divisible by the square of any prime. It follows that
$$
a+b+c = 60 + 12 + 15 = 87.
$$

Comment: The correct answer is m = 60 - 12 sqrt (15), so the answer is a + b + c = 60 + 12 + 15 = 87.

Comment: @qwr Oh, I must have had a brain fart in typing the answer. Thanks for pointing out the error.